# Why is my on_message event printing logs twice?

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is the logging bit of my on_message command, whenever I send "ping" it checks to make sure it's in its list of commands then logs it, but its logging it twice and sending once (It should only send once)...

```
async def on_message(message):
    # Check if the message was from server
    if message.content != "":
        # Test if User/ Bot
        if message.author == bot.user:
            return
        # Report Comamnd used
        else:
            splitCommand = message.content.split(" ")
            join = " "
            join = join.join(splitCommand)
            time = "[UTC " + str(message.created_at) + "]"
            singleCommand = "\nCommand: \'" + splitCommand[0] + "\'"
            multiCommand = "\nCommand: \'" + join + "\'"
            user = "\nFrom User: \'<@" + str(message.author.id) + "> | (" + str(message.author) + ")\'"
            # Single word commands
            if splitCommand[0].lower() in commandList:
                print(time + singleCommand + user)
            # Multi-word commands
            if any(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in join):
                if join.lower() in commandList:
                    print(time + multiCommand + user)
                elif regex.search(join) != None and join.lower() in commandList:
                    print(time + multiCommand + user)
            # Deletes Commands
            if message.content[0] == prefix:
                userMessage =  message
                await userMessage.delete()
                print("Deleted Command")
    else:
        pass
```

An example output would be:

```
[UTC 2020-11-24 08:21:42.587000]
Command: 'ping'
From User: '<@379355817700491264> | (24Kings#0001)'
[UTC 2020-11-24 08:21:42.587000]
Command: 'ping'
From User: '<@379355817700491264> | (24Kings#0001)'
Sent: 'pong'
```

But it should only be logging it once?
*Any ideas as to why it is logging twice and a fix would be very much appreciated!* :D

Comment: I am very derp and didn't realize I wasn't checking the length of splitCommand, so it was logging Multi-commands and single commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is better to use `discord.ext.commands`, After that you have three options.

- [on_command_error(ctx,error)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_completion#discord.on_command_error) To check for error and tell the user (permissions, wrong argument, etc..)
- [on_command(ctx)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_completion#discord.on_command)
- [on_command_completion(ctx)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_completion#discord.on_command_completion)

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_completion(ctx):
    print(f'{ctx.command} has been used by {ctx.author.display_name}')
```

For commands here is a [ref](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will add this to my logs :)
I am using the `on_command_error()` later in my code but i didn't know about `on_command()` and `on_command_completion()`, so thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Please mark it as answer <3